# gulp.src exclude all files matching a pattern except one - not working?

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp, minimatch, node-glob

This is what I've got.

```
gulp.src(["app/**/*.js" "!app/environment.*.js","app/environment.prod.js"], {read: false})
```

I was expecting it to include only environment.prod.js and exclude all other environment.*.js.  But it excludes all of them.

Only way I could get it to work is to not use wildcard for exclusion and repeat them like this.

```
gulp.src(["app/**/*.js",
          "!app/environment.test.js", 
          "!app/environment.uat.js",
          "app/environment.prod.js"], {read: false});
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you only need the `app/environment.prod.js`, then just pass that to `gulp.src`

**Edit**

```
gulp.src(["app/**/*.js", "!app/environment.+(test|uat|bla).js"], {read: false})
```

Will exclude: `app/environment.test.js, app/environment.uat.js, app/environment.bla.js`.

For reference, see this: https://github.com/isaacs/minimatch#usage

I refer to minimatch project because internally gulp uses that for their purposes

Comment: It wont work because app/**/*.js is included as well.  Sorry I will fix my question.